# DynamicJasper 5.0 Missing artifact

Tags: java, maven, dynamic-jasper

So I want to work with *DynamicJasper 5.0.0*. I copy their dependency and repository as is described on their webpage.

```
 <repositories>
     <repository>
        <id>fdvsolution.public</id>
        <url>http://archiva.fdvs.com.ar/repository/public1/</url>
     </repository>
 </repositories>

 <dependency>
     <groupId>ar.com.fdvs</groupId>
     <artifactId>DynamicJasper</artifactId>
     <version>5.0.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

I am getting a `Missing artifact ar.com.fdvs:DynamicJasper:jar:5.0.0` error in my pom. I don't understand why its not showing up since I have included the repository in my pom.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, it had nothing to do with the repository or the dependency, I had to alter my .m2 settings.xml file to allow this repository to be seen.

Comment: Hi, what was exactly the edit at settings.xml that allowed you to add the artifact? I'm running on the same issue.

Comment: its been a while and I think I removed this from my settings.xml, but this link may be helpful https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/535970/serious-problem-maven-repository

Comment: Actually there was no dependency i could try that solved this. Ended up downloading the jar file and adding it to my project's build path by myself. I downloaded the jar from here http://mvn.sonner.com.br/~maven/net/sf/jasperreports/jasperreports-htmlcomponent/5.0.1/